# Как написать запрос с группировкой по одному полю?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть две таблицы packages и packages_description.
В первом название, цена.
В другом package_id, описание.
Написал запрос для вывода пакетов и их описания. Выдало:

```
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => Старт
                [price] => 500
                [order] => 1
                [addition] => 
                [description] => 1 вариант рекламного объявления
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => Старт
                [price] => 500
                [order] => 1
                [addition] => 
                [description] => Запуск 1 рекламного объявления
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => Старт
                [price] => 500
                [order] => 1
                [addition] => 
                [description] => отчет
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 8
                [title] => Бизнес
                [price] => 1500
                [order] => 2
                [addition] => 
                [description] => отчет
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 9
                [title] => Индивидуальный
                [price] => 5000
                [order] => 3
                [addition] => от
                [description] => 
            )

    )
```

Сам запрос:

```
$packages = DB::table('packages')
        ->select(DB::raw('packages.*, packages_description.description as description'))
        ->leftJoin('packages_description', 'packages.id', '=', 'packages_description.package_id')
        ->groupBy('id', 'description')
        ->get();
```

Как нужно вывести:

```
            (
                [id] => 7
                [title] => Старт
                [price] => 500
                [order] => 1
                [addition] => 
                [description] => array( '1 вариант рекламного объявления', 'Запуск 1 рекламного объявления', 'отчет')
            )
```

Как правильно написать запрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
[description] => array( '1 вариант рекламного объявления', 'Запуск 1 рекламного
```

В laravel можно сделать метод:

```
public function getDescriptionAttribue(){
    return explode(',', $this->description);
}
```

Добавить его в поле

```
protected $appends = ['description']
```

Это как разобрать данные из базы.
Теперь запрос: тебе нужно применить группировку по полю для этого можно воспользоваться подзапросом.
Для примера:

```
select t.id, t.title, t.order, t.addition, group_concat(t.description)
from (
   select id, title, order, addition, description 
     from packages 
    where id = 7 
 group by id, title, order, addition, description
) t
```

Остается только положить этот запрос на ОРМ.